# Resize image, then resize + crop thumbnail (server speed/performance)

Tags: php, image, apache, image-resizing

I'm using `imagecreatetruecolor` and `imagejpeg` to downsize and save uploaded pictures, and create smaller square thumbnails on an Apache server with php.

Regarding server-performance, memory and speed, which is the best order to do this:

Should I use the initially stored tmp file again to create the thumbnail, or use the newly created smaller image?

The newly created downsized image is smaller (less to load?), but it is an extra file to load, and I don't know if the bigger initial tmp file is already in memory and faster for the server to **re-use** for a second resize.

> Load and resize into 2 sizes
>   VS
>   Load and resize + load new and resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the original file every time you resize, as resizing twice may produce artefacts. In terms of performance, I honestly don't think it makes any difference.

Operating systems today are quite effective in caching files, but even if they weren't, it wouldn't take a long time to load an image consisting of a few megabytes. Unless you're running a very big website, you're unlikely to notice any difference in performance in either case.

Comment: Ah yes, artifacts (quality). Like converting wav to mp3, then convert that mp3 to a smaller mp3. Maybe I should stick to re-using the initial file as you say. I guess I'm also concerned about server memory load. But let's say the initial file can be 4000 x 4000 pixels. The downsized file is only 1200 x 1200. Still use the initial file? The thumbnail will only be 300 x 300 pixels (maybe quality loss will not even be noticable)

Comment: I could make it conditional.. if the tmp file is HUGE, then use the downsized version to create thumbnail. If the tmp file is not huge, then just re-use that

Comment: I would guess that it depends on your usecase. However, I would think that you'll run into PHPs memory limit on the first resize before it becomes a strain on CPU/storage.

Comment: Ah yes PHP memory too, should've mentioned it. Oh well, I will try to use the tmp file for it all, and only resize the resized file if the tmp file is huge